# Evaluate the Expected Value

Tags: probability

> Assume that $\Bbb E[X]=3$ and $\mathbb{Var}(X)=5$. Evaluate $\Bbb E[(X+2)(X+3)]$.

Would the $E[(X+3)(X+2)] = E[x+2]$ multiply by $E[x+3]$? Where does the variance fit in this equation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general the expected value of a product is not the product of expectations, this is true only in specific cases. But the expected value is always linear, so use it. $(X+3)(X+2)=X^2+5X+6$.

Comment: No. Expectation is linear. Expand the $(X+3)(X+2)$ and you will see where the variance comes in.

Answer (score 1):

- In general $E[XY] \ne E[X] E[Y]$ for random variables $X$ and $Y$. (Equality does hold when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.) In your case, $X+2$ and $X+3$ are definitely not independent, so you cannot immediately claim that $E[(X+3)(X+2)] = E[X+3]E[X+2]$.
- $E[(X+3)(X+2)] = E[X^2 + 5X + 6] = E[X^2] + 5 E[X] + 6$, where the last equality is due to *linearity of expectation*, a very important property. (That is, $E[aX+Y] = a E[X] + E[Y]$ for any random variables $X$ and $Y$.)
- You have $E[X]$ given already, but you don't know $E[X^2]$. But note that $\text{Var}(X)$ is given to you. How are $\text{Var}(X)$ and $E[X^2]$ related?

Comment: Var(x) = E(x^2) - (E(X))^2. Would it be 5 = E(x^2) +(3^2). So E(x^2) = -4? Then [2]+5[]+6 = -4 +5(3) + 6? So the final solution would be 17?